# How to list newly added files based on some name pattern or file extention in git per commit?

Tags: git

I can list list files in which are newly added per commit using command

`git whatchanged --diff-filter=A`

If lot of people are working on some big project then output will be big. suppose I want to list only newly file of certain type e.g. `.h` header files.

What should be the command for listing newly added file of certain type based on file name? `git whatchanged --diff-filter=A | grep '.h$'` is not a right solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git log` command (`git whatchanged` is short for `git log --raw --no-merges`) takes the same options as [`git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) in terms of reducing which commits are to be shown.  One such option (or multiple options, really, since you can list more than one path) is `-- <paths>`.  What the documentation omits here is that the `<paths>` part can include wildcards.

Hence:

```
git log --raw --no-merges --diff-filter=A -- '*.h'
```

does the trick, because `'*.h'` selects only commits that affect at least one pathname ending in `.h`; `git log` (or `git whatchanged`) extends this to reporting only the affected files; and then `--diff-filter=A` discards commits that do not *add* any such files.